# List a column's value only once for repeating IDs

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with modifying my query to only show the PlannedAmount once per ProjectID. Any rows with repeating ProjectIDs should have a PlannedAmount of null.

Base Table:

```
+------------------------------------+
| ProjectID SegmentName   CurrentMTD |
+------------------------------------+
| 100       Taxes-state    20000     |
| 100       Taxes-federal 100000     |
| 101       Building           0     |
| 102       Land               0     |
| 103       Equipment      25000     |
+------------------------------------+
```

PlannedAmounts Table:

```
+-------------------------+
| ProjectID PlannedAmount |
+-------------------------+
| 100       140000        |
| 103        30000        |
+-------------------------+
```

My query:

```
SELECT a.ProjectID, a.SegmentName, a.CurrentMTD, NVL(b.PlannedAmount, 0) as PlannedAmount 
FROM Base AS a LEFT JOIN PlannedAmounts AS b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID;
```

Result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ProjectID SegmentName   CurrentMTD  PlannedAmount |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 100       Taxes-state    20000      140000        |
| 100       Taxes-federal 100000      140000        |
| 101       Building           0           0        |
| 102       Land               0           0        |
| 103       Equipment      25000       30000        |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

What I want:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ProjectID SegmentName   CurrentMTD  PlannedAmount |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 100       Taxes-state    20000      140000        |
| 100       Taxes-federal 100000                    |
| 101       Building           0           0        |
| 102       Land               0           0        |
| 103       Equipment      25000       30000        |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I don't want to repeat the PlannedAmount for any repeating ProjectIDs - I only want to show it once - on the first occurence of any given ProjectID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Case and Row_Number(), Your modified query

```
SELECT a.ProjectID, a.SegmentName, a.CurrentMTD, Case when Row_number() (over partition by a.ProjectId order by a.ProjectId) = 1 then NVL(b.PlannedAmount, 0) else NULL end as PlannedAmount  
    FROM Base AS a LEFT JOIN PlannedAmounts AS b ON a.ProjectID = b.ProjectID;
```